# how do i make a library installation available to different rubies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I am attempting to install the librets library.  I can use rvm to switch to the system ruby (1.8.7) and install librets and it seems fine.  I am then able to require librets.  But then if I switch to ruby 1.9.2 with rvm and i try to require librets, it says no such file to load.  So how do I install a library so it works across rubies.  Or how do I install specific to each ruby so it works there.  1.9.2 is the version I need most.

FYI, librets is not a gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you can use `my_use_ruby=yes`

https://gist.github.com/977074#gistcomment-36462

Answer (score 2):

For installing a library when using rvm, you can use `rvm ruby-1.9.2 gem install librets` and that will install the library for the specific ruby version. However another neat alternative to achieve what you desire can be achieved using gemsets.

```
rvm use system
rvm gemset create librets
rvm gemset use librets
gem install librets
rvm use ruby-1.9.2
rvm gemset create librets
rvm getset copy ruby-1.8.7@librets ruby-1.9.2@librets
rvm gemset use librets
```

Although I believe the above is a little too cumbersome when you want only 1 particular gem, but if it is a series of gems that you want, copying gemsets can be a big time saver.

Comment: librets is not a gem.  It is a c library.  That is why I am having the issue.

Comment: @kidbrax my bad, if you wish to use the library to build a RETS client, then perhaps you should have a look at - https://github.com/josephholsten/rets4r instead. If you want to use librets only, then you might have to update the $LOAD_PATH to make sure librets is in it even when you switch to a different ruby.

Comment: Thanks.  I have been using rets4r but am having a few issues so am looking into librets.